# How to get rid of dotted line on content

Tags: css, border, dotted-line

Some times I see a black-dotted border like line around text or content when clicked. That mostly happen with Firefox. I tried to set `border: none;` to get rid of it with no success.

[image: button with updated code. Issue unresolved]

Here is the sample code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="sub">
        <button>Show</button>
    </div>
</div>
<span>
    <button  class="styled-button">
         Click
    </button>
</span>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
button {
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration:0;
    -moz-outline-style: 0;
}
.styled-button {
    color: #fff;
    background: green;
    height: 36px;
    width: 145px;
    padding: 2px 25px;
    margin: 10px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
   -moz-outline-style: none;
}
span {
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration:0;
}
```

Could any one suggest me a fix for that? Why does it appear at first place?

**Update**:

I thought I was able to fix it at some point. But some of my content still has the issue and that is in Mozilla **Firefox**. I have updated the question with code. Please check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/gfvCm/)

Comment: what language you are using and what control they are?

Comment: `outline:none`, maybe?

Comment: @IamSJ: JSFiddle would be nice :)

Comment: @AliGajani  Actually, that was for a WordPress site. Will try to replicate the similar in a fiddle and post it here.

Comment: You jsfiddle works fine for me

Comment: @SurjithSM Can you try in Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: @Gourav Tried the same in fiddle. No success.

Comment: Tried on mozilla too. Works fine. Which version are you using? Latest is 26.0

Comment: @SurjithSM Using the same- http://i.imgur.com/f7igUbz.png :). Don't know why that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar issues in the past and it's usually been a simple trick to stop this dotted line syndrome from appearing on your content. This is how I do it:

```
   outline: 0;
   border: 0;
```

Comment: It works here, it works for everyone too. Looks like you have some code inspector on and you don't know it. Have you tried a different machine? If it's not there, it means there's nothing wrong with your code as such.

Comment: Checked on three of my machines. As stated in the question, I have no problem on Chrome browser. But it is on Firefox. Can you confirm it works on Firefox for you?

Comment: I just checked it on my Firefox. It works as well. :). Does it show up on all of your machines (FF).

Comment: Hmm, I am confused now. Checked at Work place and it works fine there. But my two desktops at home and a Notebook gives that trouble. All the three computers use Firefox 26.0. Might be the issue with addons or something? Will check that out.

Comment: Good to see it works there, and let me reassure you, it works here too, so there is nothing wrong with the code. Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

consider
`<a href="#">click</a>`

Now to remove the outline you need to apply some css

```
a{
   outline:0;
  }
```

styling for any way a link is about to be used

```
 a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
     // style it
  }
```

For Firefox inputs you can try

```
  input::-moz-focus-inner { 
     border: 0; 
   }
```

For IE9 you can use the below

```
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

You can also try for

```
 a{
    outline: 0;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
  }
```

Comment: Anyhow, I tried anchor element. Also `input::-moz-focus-inner ` don't work for me. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjeev/gfvCm/8/)